# Does the Future trait implementation "force" you to break noalias in rust?

Tags: rust, async-await, alias, rust-futures

I'llI was thinking about the rust async infrastructure and at the heart of the API lies the [Future trait](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/future/trait.Future.html) which is:

```rust
pub trait Future {
    type Output;

    fn poll(self: Pin<&mut Self>, cx: &mut Context<'_>) -> Poll<Self::Output>;
}
```

According to the docs

> The core method of future, `poll`, attempts to resolve the future into a final value. This method does not block if the value is not ready. Instead, the current task is scheduled to be woken up when it’s possible to make further progress by polling again. The context passed to the poll method can provide a `Waker`, which is a handle for waking up the current task.

This implies that the `Context` value passed to `.poll()` (particularly the waker) needs some way to refer to the pinned future `&mut self` in order to wake it up. However `&mut` implies that the reference is not aliased. Am I misunderstanding something or is this a "special case" where aliasing `&mut` is allowed? If the latter, are there other such special cases besides `UnsafeCell`?

Comment: I'm no expert on this by any means, so take this with a grain of salt, but I think it's important to distinguish between a `Future` and a task here. As the quote says, the `Waker` doesn't wake the `Future`, it wakes up the task that the `Future` is being executed on. As far as I know, a `Waker` contains no information about the `Future` it was given to. Maybe [this example from "Asynchronous Programming in Rust"](https://rust-lang.github.io/async-book/02_execution/03_wakeups.html#task-wakeups-with-waker) illustrates this point.

Comment: Well on the very next page if the book you will notice that task contains a boxed future and the waker is created from a reference to task. So there is a reference to future held from task albeit indirect. How could there not be? `waker.wake()` eventually triggers a transition for the state machine that is the `Future`

Answer (score 3):

> needs some way to refer to the pinned future `&mut self` in order to wake it up.

No, it doesn't. The key thing to understand is that a “task” is not the future: it is the future *and what the executor knows about it.* What exactly the waker mutates is up to the executor, but it must be something that *isn't* the `Future`. I say “must” not just because of Rust mutability rules, but because `Future`s *don't contain* any state that says whether they have been woken. So, there isn't anything there to usefully mutate; 100% of the bytes of the future's memory are dedicated to the specific `Future` implementation and none of the executor's business.

> Well on the very next page if the book you will notice that task contains a boxed future and the waker is created from a reference to task. So there is a reference to future held from task albeit indirect.

OK, let's look at [those data structures](https://rust-lang.github.io/async-book/02_execution/04_executor.html#applied-build-an-executor). Condensed:

```rust
struct Executor {
    ready_queue: Receiver<Arc<Task>>,
}

struct Task {
    future: Mutex<Option<BoxFuture<'static, ()>>>,
    task_sender: SyncSender<Arc<Task>>,
}
```

The reference to the task is an `Arc<Task>`, and the future itself is inside a `Mutex` (interior mutability) in the task. Therefore,

1. It is not possible to get an `&mut Task` from the `Arc<Task>`, because `Arc` doesn't allow that.
2. The `future` is in a `Mutex` which does run-time checking that there is at most one mutable reference to it.

The only things you can do with an `Arc<Task>` are

- clone it and send it
- get `&` access to the `future` in a `Mutex` (which allows *requesting* run-time-checked mutation access to the `Future`)
- get `&` access to the `task_sender` (which allows sending things to `ready_queue`).

So, in this case, when the waker is called, it sort-of doesn't even mutate anything specific to the `Task` at all: it makes a clone of the `Arc<Task>` (which increments an atomic reference count stored next to the `Task`) and puts it on the `ready_queue` (which mutates storage shared between the `Sender` and `Receiver`).

Another executor might indeed have task-specific state in the `Task` that is mutated, such as a flag marking that the task is already woken and doesn't need to be woken again. That flag might be stored in an `AtomicBoolean` field in the task. But still, it does not alias with any `&mut` of the `Future` because it's not part of the `Future`, but the task.

---

All that said, there actually *is* something special about `Future`s and noalias — but it's not about executors, it's about `Pin`. Pinning explicitly allows the pinned type to contain “self-referential” pointers into itself, so Rust does not declare noalias for `Pin<&mut T>`. However, exactly what the language rules around this are is still not quite rigorously specified; the current situation is just considered a kludge so that `async` functions can be correctly compiled, I think.

Comment: The current situation is that `!Unpin` removes `noalias`, but yes, it is considered a temporary hack.

Answer (score 2):

There is no such special case. Judging from your comment about the Rust executor, you are misunderstanding how interior mutability works.

The example in the Rust book uses an `Arc` wrapped `Task` structure, with the future contained in a `Mutex`. When the task is run, it locks the mutex and obtains the singular `&mut` reference that's allowed to exist.

Now look at how the example implements `wake_by_ref`, and notice how it never touches the `future` at all. Indeed, that function would not be able to lock the future at all, as the upper level already has the lock. It would not be able to safely get a `&mut` reference, and so it prevents you from doing so, therefore, no issue.

The restriction for `UnsafeCell` and its wrappers is that only one `&mut` reference may exist for an object at any point in time. However, multiple `&` immutable references may exist to the `UnsafeCell` or structures containing it just fine - that is the point of interior mutability.